# VBA : Enexpected running VBA from cmd line

Tags: vba, cmd, powerpoint

I wanted to open an existing ppt using Wscript and modify it. For that I am opening the file in visual studio editor and executing the script from cmd in windows using `WScript hi.vbs`

But when I ran the same code I am getting error.

```
Expected end of statement in line 4
```

Line 4 looks like `Dim objNewPowerPoint As Object`
However Same case works when I run code in excel VBA editor.

When I am removing the As object I am not getting any error nor any changes are happening in the PPT file. 
Wondering what is the possible issue.

I am not using excel vba or word vba i am just running the file from `cmd`

```
Sub Open_an_existing_Presentations()

Dim objNewPowerPoint As Object
Dim MyPresentation  As Object
Dim pSlides  As Object

Set objNewPowerPoint = CreateObject(PowerPoint.Application)
'Make this Application Object Visible
objNewPowerPoint.Visible = True
```

Please help me how can i modify and more importantly how to see both errors compile and syntax.

FYI : I am completely new into VBA and I am trying to update a PPT and wanted to run vba script from another program so trying something like this. Best suggestions are always welcome

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* The first thing you need to realize in regards to your question is that [tag:vba], [tag:vbscript], [tag:vb.net], [tag:vb6] etc are all similar, but **not** interchangeable.  You can't run `VBA` from the command line.  You are probably thinking of [tag:VBScript] (`VBS`).  Given that information, you might to some Googling into how to run the commands your trying to run, but in `VBS` instead.

Comment: An overview on Wikipedia: [**VBA**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) and [**VBS**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript). Also [Common Things You Can Do with VBScript](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/outlook-vba/articles/common-things-you-can-do-with-vbscript)

Comment: VBScript is untyped, so to declare a variable you must just `Dim X` not `Dim X as SomeType`

Comment: yeah i got that but why not it is throwing any error when in statements like  `Set MyPresentation = objNewPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\vmishra\Desktop\PPT-Slides.pptx") `consider ppt path is wrong I am running like `Wscript hi.vbs`

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you cannot dim something as something.

```
Dim objNewPowerPoint
Dim MyPresentation
Dim pSlides
```

And `dim` is optional and serves no technical purpose in VBS (it merely catches spelling mistakes if `Option Explicit` is specified, else it does nothing at all as in your case except take time to the process the line). In compiled languages it allocates storage and checks data types when using it.

When you use `Set =` VBS knows it an object and makes it one (4 x 32 bit integers - One a reference count and another a memory address of the function table for the object - two are unused). If you use `x=5555` vbs knows it's a integer.

Comment: So that's what is typically called a *Variant* data type... Using `Dim` in VBScripts might improve readability, that's why I'm usually doing it...

Comment: Still the variant is set to a particular data type. See http://ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/Handouts/cse775/presentations/BruceMcKinneyPapers/variants.htm It used to be an MS paper.